# How do I call char * arr[]

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

Assuming we have something like this:

```
char * arr[] = { "string1", "string2" };
```

How do I / more formally (or more accurately) / call this variable:

- Array of strings
- Array of pointers to string
- Array of char pointers

---

UPDATE:
I will provide a [source](http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/argc-and-argv.html) in which I read "array of strings" in a response to people saying that this is invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both

- Array of pointers to string
- Array of char pointers

are correct.

```
char * arr[] = { "string1", "string2" };
```

is an array of `char*` pointers each pointing to the corresponding string literal.

Comment: Just like I thought. I just saw in several occasions "array of strings" which confuses a lot and made me uncertain. Can you suggest a better question title?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use vector of strings if you are using c++
because it gives you a lot of predefined operations.

```
std :: vector<std :: string> ar;
```

now you can push any string you want

Comment: mods need to create a thicker C tag (for e.g with the Arial-64 font). So that it becomes more obvious. Red glowing on it makes it a greater idea.

Comment: Its all about your question requirements

Comment: Would be so, if I didn't explicitly tagged __C__ they are very different when it comes to using name spaces.

Comment: Why answer a question with "if you are using c++" if the question is clearly tagged with [tag:c] and not [tag:c++]? Also, you do not answer the question.